# set directory with action listener

Tags: java

I have a rename tool that sets a folder directory, however I created some JCheckBox and I want them to be able to change the directory depending on which is selected.

Her is the action listener for the checkbox, it edits the txt field so it looks right on the program but does not actually change the directory.

```
cbxBlackBerry = new JCheckBox("BlackBerry");
        cbxBlackBerry.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            if(cbxBlackBerry.isSelected())
                            txtPrefix.setText("x-rimdevice_");
                        else{
                            txtPrefix.setText("");
                        }

                        if(cbxBlackBerry.isSelected())
                            txtDirectory.setText("\\RSASoftToken\\blackberry");
                        else{
                            txtDirectory.setText("");
                        }
                    }
                }
            ); //close addActionListener
```

this is the code that commands the directory setting

```
private boolean chooseDirectory(){

        /* Choose the file Directory
         * this will ensure that the class variable directory get the value
         * only when a directory is chosen, then the button Ok will be enabled
         */

        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        int returnval = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

        if(returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            directory = fc.getSelectedFile();
            btnOk.setEnabled(true);
            return true;        
        }

        return false;
    }// end chooseDirectory
```

How do I modify this code to actually change the directory?

```
if(cbxBlackBerry.isSelected())
                            txtDirectory.setText("\\RSASoftToken\\blackberry");
                        else{
                            txtDirectory.setText("");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a method like this:

```
private void setDirectory(File dir) {
  directory = dir;
  txtDirectory.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

and where you have code that sets the directory JTextField, call this method instead. So for instance, instead of

```
if(cbxBlackBerry.isSelected())
   txtDirectory.setText("\\RSASoftToken\\blackberry");
else{
   txtDirectory.setText("");
}
```

Do something like:

```
String dirPath = "";
if (cbxBlackBerry.isSelected())
   dirPath = BLACKBERRY_PATH; // a constant
else {
   dirPath = "";
}
setDirectory(new File(dirPath));
```

And at the top of the class, have a constant if need be:

```
private static final String BLACKBERRY_PATH = "\\RSASoftToken\\blackberry";
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll use a [ChangeListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/ja/6/docs/ja/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) class

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class JCheckboxApp {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBox Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JCheckBox cbxBlackBerry = new JCheckBox("BlackBerry");
    final JTextField txtPrefix = new JTextField("textPrefix");
    final JTextField txtDirectory = new JTextField("txtDirectory");
    cbxBlackBerry.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
            JCheckBox source = (JCheckBox) changeEvent.getSource();
            if (source.isSelected()) {
                txtPrefix.setText("x-rimdevice_");
                txtDirectory.setText("\\RSASoftToken\\blackberry");
            } else {
                txtPrefix.setText("");
                txtDirectory.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(txtPrefix);
    p.add(txtDirectory);
    p.add(cbxBlackBerry);
    frame.add(p);
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: great! now how? can you give me an example?